# How Do I Make an NFC Tag Open and App, or Website Where No App Present

Tags: android, ios, nfc

I want to have my NFC tags open my app on a user's device - where the app is installed. If the app is not installed however, I simply want it to take them to our website instead. Is there any way to write this logic into an NFC tag?

As a bonus question, is there any way to write logic in that would allow it to launch different apps (depending on whether the device is Apple or Android), and failing both those checks, launch the website?

Comment: For Apple, I know you can use this URL that either opens the app if it's installed, if not then it'll open the app store for them to download the app. You'll need to look up the new Docs to find out how as they have updated them for the Upcoming IOS 14. The url would be yourapp://someid. You stick that url into the nfc tag and itll run that url. To make it for both devices, you could make a webpage that determines the users OS, then direct them to the correct URL form your website. Say if and iPhone was used, then direct them to the URL I mentioned earlier on.